# How to know if user swipe extent left where no tab to show into tabarView

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs, scrollview, tabbar

How can i detect if user swipe left or right extent where no tab to show , i need to make action if is so like call function... i need this for several things .. is it possible ?

```
     @override
              void initState() {
                super.initState();
                _controllerr =   TabController( length: 2, vsync: this );
                _controllerr!.addListener(test);
              }
        
         test(){
    print('max left extent is scrolled '); 
// here will outputa only when tab changed but not when swipe right or left extent where no page to show 
         
          }
        
        
        
        bottom:TabBar(
          controller:  _controllerr,
               
          tabs: const [
           Tab(text: "page 1",),
          Tab(text: "page 2",),
        
         ],
        ),
        
        
         TabBarView(
            controller: _controllerr,
            children: [
        Twxt('page1')
        Twxt('page2')
        ]
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out. you know the no of tabs.

```
  TabBarView(
            controller: _controllerr,
            children: [
                      Twxt('page1')
                      Twxt('page2')
                      ]
            )
```

no of tabs = no of screens

so you know which is the first and last tabs.

so the wrap  `Twxt('first_page')` , `Twxt('last_page')` with [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

for first_page :

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onPanUpdate: (details) { 
     // for right swipe 
    if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
        //your work
     }
  },
  child: Twxt('first_page'),
)
```

for last_page :

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onPanUpdate: (details) {
   
    // for left swipe 
    if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
          //your work
      }
  },
  child: Twxt('last_page'),
)
```

hope this will work

Comment: thanks it is work BUT GestureDetector will disable the normal scroll of tabBarView , but i found solution that is not disable GestureDetector , the same way but with Listener widget instead of GestureDetector .. however you deserve mark as good answer